# Find all rows of matrix equal to vector

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following matrix:

```
cm<-structure(c(100, 200, 400, 800, 100, 200, 400, 800, 100, 200, 
400, 800, 100, 200, 400, 800, 100, 200, 400, 800, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 
-0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, -0.4, 
-0.4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), .Dim = c(20L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Var1", "Var2", "Var3", "n1")))
```

and another matrix derived from it:

```
a4<-data.matrix(unique(cm[,1:3]))
```

Now, I want to find all the rows of `cm` whose first three columns are equal to `a4[1,]`, but doing the intutive thing:

```
a5<-which(cm[,1:3]==a4[1,])
```

fails (`R 3.1.3`). For example `a5[2]` is 13, but the 13th row of `cm[,1:3]` ain't the same as `a4[1,]`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `apply` and `all.equal` to compare each row against the target row. The problem with using `==` is that it only checks the it recycles elements of a vector for comparison, whereas you want to see if all values in the row vector match `a4[1,]` so you should use `all.equal`. The consequence is that it's return value is not a logical but instead a character string describing differences between the objects, which makes it a little messier to work with than `==` alone:

```
which(apply(cm, 1, function(x) all.equal(x[1:3], a4[1,])) == "TRUE")
# [1] 1
```

You can also make that a bit simpler by using `identical` instead of `all.equal`:

```
which(apply(cm, 1, function(x) identical(x[1:3], a4[1,])))
# [1] 1
```

Then extract:

```
cm[apply(cm, 1, function(x) identical(x[1:3], a4[1,])),,drop=FALSE]
#      Var1 Var2 Var3 n1
# [1,]  100    0 -0.4  1
```

To clarify exactly what's happening, consider what `==` does implicitly when you pass a matrix argument:

```
which(cm[,1:3]==a4[1,])
# [1]  1 13 23 35 42 45 48 51 53 56 59
```

That result is the same as converting the matrix to a vector:

```
as.vector(cm[,1:3])
#  [1] 100.0 200.0 400.0 800.0 100.0 200.0 400.0 800.0 100.0 200.0 400.0 800.0 100.0 200.0 400.0 800.0 100.0 200.0 400.0 800.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.5   0.5   0.5
# [28]   0.5   1.0   1.0   1.0   1.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.5   0.5   0.5   0.5  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4  -0.4   0.0   0.0
# [55]   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0   0.0
which(as.vector(cm[,1:3])==a4[1,])
# [1]  1 13 23 35 42 45 48 51 53 56 59
```

Thus, the positions are positions within the vector representation of `cm`, not rows in the matrix representation. `==` comparisons can also be dangerous (again do to the recycling noted above) when trying to compare vectors that are not of equivalent length or where one vector's length is not a multiple of the other, which will produce a warning:

```
1:2 == 1:3
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# Warning message:
# In 1:2 == 1:3 :
#   longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Whereas there is no warning when recycling is used:

```
1:2 == 1:6
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Thanks: Has this behaviour of '==' applied on vectors changed? I seem to recall that it would have worked at some time in the past.

Comment: @Thomas @user189035   `==` doesn't always use the first element in a vector, but it does recycle..`a <- 1:4; b <- 1:4;c <- 1:2;a==b;a==c`

Comment: @user189035 Hasn't changed. I've made some edits that hopefully clarify things.

Comment: @Thomas thanks, any idea why `rowSums(abs(sweep(cm[,1:3],2,a4[1,],FUN='-')))` would returns wired results (not a vector as I would expect)? Or you say this is also due to recycling?

Comment: What do you expect the result to be? I get a vector, which is what I would expect.

Comment: Can you do this without apply?  Vectorize it?

Comment: @robertevansanders I don't think so, but you're welcome to try!

Answer (score 8):

The function `row.match` in `prodlim` is easy to use, and ideal for your problem.

```
library(prodlim)
row.match(a4[1,], cm[,1:3])
[1] 1
```

Comment: This code only returns the first match, which is not what the op asked for.

Comment: Although I do think it was what the user actually wanted +1

Comment: No, I can confirm, the OP wanted *all* the matches (+1 for the interesting function though).

Answer (score 1):

Storing the row to be matched and main table as dataframes and calling plyr's match_df.

Firstly, understanding the matching process.

```
plyr::match_df(data.frame(cm[,1:3]),
           data.frame(t(a4[1,])))

# Matching on: Var1, Var2, Var3
# Var1 Var2 Var3
# 1  100    0 -0.4
```

Now, using another case. Matching using two columns and extracting the rownumber to slice the dataframe.

```
cm[plyr::match_df(data.frame(cm[,c(1,3)]),
               data.frame(t(cm[3,c(1,3)]))) %>% rownames() %>% as.numeric(),]

# 
# Matching on: Var1, Var3
# Var1 Var2 Var3 n1
# [1,]  400  0.0 -0.4  1
# [2,]  400  0.5 -0.4  1
# [3,]  400  1.0 -0.4  1
```