# Find subarrays of a multidimensional array equal to a specified array in R

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, indexing

Consider a simple toy problem.

```
#build array, A, with its last dimension filled with randomly selected rows from matrix G
 set.seed(1)
 n=2
 G = matrix(c(0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0), 3, 3) 
 inds = matrix( ceiling( 3 * runif( n^2 ) ), n, n ) 
 A = array(0, dim = c(n, n, 3))
 for(i in 1:n){ 
   for(j in 1:n){
      A[i, j, ] = G[inds[i,j],]
   }
 }
```

I would like to create a matrix, `R`, with each entry `R[i,j]` containing the row `r` of `G` such that `A[i,j,] == G[r,]`.

Thes answer to the above is

```
R =[1, 2;
    2, 3]
```

There are lots of [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29345263/find-all-rows-of-matrix-equal-to-vector) here on matching rows of a matrix to a vector, but thought I'd ask the more general question.

Comment: Is "A" and "G", indeed, binary? You could map each `A[i, j, ]` and `G[r, ]` to a single value and match them -- `p = 2 ^ (0:(dim(A)[3] - 1)); mapA = rowSums(A * p[slice.index(A, 3)], dims = 2); mapG = rowSums(G * p[col(G)]); array(match(mapA, mapG), dim(mapA))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `row.match` from the package `prodsim` I came up with the following, which I believe could be generalized to find any subarray of an array equal to a specified array

```
apply(A, c(1,2), function(x) row.match(x,G))
```

But perhaps there are other, better ways?