# Why won't all.equal find me a vector in a list of vectors?

Tags: r, vector, match, permutation

I'm trying to write some code to find a specific vector in a huge array of vectors and return the indexes of where copies of that vector appear. In an attempt to debug, I'm trying to learn the behavior of `all.equal` (recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29345370/10319707), `identical` appears to be ruled out by a type mismatch). I have now wrote the following code:

```
data<-replicate(100000,sample(4)) 
which( apply(data, 2, function(x) all.equal(c(1:4),data)) == TRUE)
```

As I understand it, the first line of what I have written generates a massive number of permutations of the whole numbers from 1 to 4 and the second line searches them for any occasions of the exact permutation 1, 2, 3, 4. Statistically speaking, I'm very confident that this permutation should appear somewhere in this list and in my particular case, it's the ninth entry. However, every time that I have ran this code or any variation on it, I've been told that the desired permutation never appears.

What am I doing wrong? Frankly, I begun suspecting that I was making a major mistake when I had to look up how to find a vector in a list of vectors and that I had to use two functions to do so. Is there a much simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
which( apply(data, 2, function(x) all.equal(c(1:4),x)) == TRUE)
```

The difference is that in your code you are comparing the entire structure called `data` to 1:4, which will never be `TRUE` since the sizes don't match.  I replaced `data` with `x` inside of the function that is being applied, so now each individual column is being compared to 1:4.

You also have some redundancies in your code, `c(1:4)` is the same as `1:4`. And `all.equal` is probably overkill in this case since it is doing more than just comparing (it compares with a fuzz factor, and tells you how the things are different).  The way you are using it you are converting your `TRUE`s to character.  It would be more efficient to not simplify ahead of time.  Here is a quick comparison (smaller simulated data):

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> 
> microbenchmark(
+   ae = {
+     data<-replicate(100,sample(4)) 
+     which( apply(data, 2, function(x) all.equal(c(1:4),x)) == TRUE)
+   },
+   e = {
+     data <- replicate(100, sample(4), simplify=FALSE)
+     which(sapply(data, function(x)all(x==(1:4))))
+   }
+ )
Unit: microseconds
 expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq       max neval cld
   ae 4063.205 4303.3370 4940.2126 4501.5080 4951.623 10953.339   100   b
    e  455.934  493.3115  578.4828  523.4605  562.601  2013.444   100  a
```

The simplified code runs in about one ninth (on average) of the time.

Comment: How have you dropped the (data, 2,) part with sapply? Doesn't sapply need to know that it's only looking at the columns?

Comment: @J.Mini, in the code with `sapply` I specified `simplify=FALSE` in the call to `replicate`.  The result is that `replicate` returns a list instead of a matrix and `sapply` works directly on the list.  Part of the speed up may be skipping the step where `replicate` converts the list to a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you were almost there, it is just a small typo. The correct code is

```
which(apply(data, 2, function(x) all.equal(x, c(1, 2, 3, 4))) == TRUE)
```

as you need to supply the data for comparison and the necessary data is the columns and not the whole data set. The way you did it, it will never find a match because the whole array will never match one vector.